# Email formatting in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to send an email to a customer that has just completed a transaction but I am having some difficulties in drafting out the format in code behind, this is my code, apparently it's appearing as one straight line of text in the body of my mail, how can I format it in such a way it appears something like, any help is appreciated, thanks :

```
Thank you for shopping with us. Your purchase details are as follow:

Product ID           Model Number          Model Name         Unit Cost    Quantity    ItemTotal 

357                       P1        AK47 Rifle(free 30 * 7.62)   $2.99          1        2.99 

362                     XT3893        Mirage stealth tank       $500000.99      1    500000.99  


                                                                              Total:$500002.99
```

This is my code:

```
                MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
                MembershipUser u = users[UserName];

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(u.Email);
                mail.From = new MailAddress("me@hotmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "Purchase invoice" + newOrder.OrderID;

                string bodyText = "";
                double unitQtyPrice = 0;
                double totalPrice = 0;
                foreach (var cItem in cartList)
                {
                    Math.Round(cItem.UnitCost, 2);

                    bodyText = bodyText + '\n' 
                               + cItem.ProductID.ToString() + '\t'
                               + cItem.ModelName + '\t'
                               + cItem.ModelNumber + '\t'
                               + cItem.UnitCost.ToString() + '\t'
                               + cItem.Quantity.ToString() + '\t';

                     unitQtyPrice = cItem.Quantity * (double)cItem.UnitCost;
                     totalPrice += unitQtyPrice;          
                }

                Math.Round(totalPrice, 2);
                mail.Body = "Thank you for shopping with us. Your purchase details are as follow:"
                    + '\n' + "ProductID:" + '\t' + "ModelName" + '\t' + "ModelNumber" + '\t' + "UnitPrice" + '\t' + "Quantity"
                    + '\n' + bodyText + '\n' + '\n' + '\t' + '\t' + "Total Price:" + totalPrice ;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
                client.EnableSsl = true; //ssl must be enabled for hotmail
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("me@hotmail.com", "xxxx");
                client.Credentials = credentials;
                try
                {
                    client.Send(mail);
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    throw new Exception("ERROR: Fail to send email - " + exp.Message.ToString(), exp);
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have it set to HTML, which is whitespace-insensitive.  If you want it to be sent as plaintext with line breaks and all, don't set `IsBodyHtml`.

Alternatively, you can include actual HTML markup to lay out your email, which may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just write you mail.Body part in an HTML language...

and set

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```